# Doing `call` on function that does `fork` causes return to hang on return?

Tags: redux-saga

I am doing `call` on a function like this:

```
const didRefresh = yield call(maybeRefresh);
console.log('call - maybeRefresh, didRefresh:', didRefresh); // i expect this to return before the fetch in refreshTask completes
```

And `maybeRefresh` is this:

```
function* maybeRefresh() {
    const shouldRefresh = true;

    if (shouldRefresh) {
        yield fork(refreshTask);
        console.log('did fork refresh task, should now return while refreshTask happens async');
    }

    const didRefresh = shouldRefresh;
    return didRefresh;
}

function* refreshTask() {
    console.log('will fetch');
    const res = yield call(fetch, 'http://www.blah.com');
    console.log('ok refresh done, status:', res.status); // however its not return until here
}
```

When I fork the `refreshTask`, I expect the `yield call` at top to return a value BEFORE the fetch happens. However even though "did fork" gets logged, it seems it hangs even though its ready to return. It hangs on return until the forked task `refreshTask` completes, then it returns. Is this how `yield call` works? It works for any async stuff started by the child to finish?

Comment: Not sure whether it's a duplicate of this, but for sure my answer here covers the question in detail, please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48054800/2998898)

Comment: Thanks @Grigoryan you're correct! I didn't understand that sentence in the docs till now. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between fork and spawn in redux-saga?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43259301/whats-the-difference-between-fork-and-spawn-in-redux-saga)