# Lots of inputs but only one button submit in redux-saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

The problem is that I have several inputs and one button to save the data. I have this method in my component in react:

```
handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.props.newEmail ? this.props.onSaveNewEmail(this.props.newEmail) : null;
    this.props.newName ? this.props.onSaveNewName(this.props.newName) : null;
  }
```

And this method is captured in my redux saga:

```
export function* isName() {
  const name = yield select(makeNewNameSelector());
  ...

  // validation name
  if (!re.test(name)) {
    ...
  } else {
    // ! OK, I CAN UPDATE NAME BECAUSE NEW NAME IS OK
  }
}

export function* isEmail() {
  const email = yield select(makeNewEmailSelector());
  const requestURL = `/api/users/isEmail/${email}`;
  ...

  // validation email
  if (!re.test(email)) {
    ...
  } else {
    try {
      const response = yield call(request, requestURL);
      if (!response.isEmail) {
        // ! OK, I CAN UPDATE EMAIL BECAUSE IT DOESN'T HAVE IN MY DB MYSQL
      }
    } catch (err) {
      ...
    }
  }
}

// this method send request PUT and this can update data:
function* saveData() {
  const name = yield select(makeNewNameSelector());
  const email = yield select(makeNewEmailSelector());
  ...

  try {
    const response = yield call(request, requestURL, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name,
        email,
      }),
    });

    if (response.success) {
      name ? yield put(enterNewNameSuccessAction()) : null;
      email ? yield put(enterNewEmailSuccessAction()) : null;
      yield put(saveDataSuccessAction());
    }
  } catch (err) {
    ...
  }
}

export default function* settingsPageSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(ENTER_NEW_NAME, isName);
  yield takeLatest(ENTER_NEW_EMAIL, isEmail);
}
```

And now how should I call my `saveData()` method only once?

If in place of the comments I put a `yield call(saveData)`, it will work, but this will send a **two request**! I would like to send only one PUT request.

and if I want to change the e-mail, I have to wait until my code will check if such e-mail exists in the database. if not, then only change action.

Comment: If you came up with a different solution please, let us know... if it helped you, please accept my answer. Both could be really useful for other users looking for the same (or a similar) answer 

Answer (score 0):

You need to play with Redux-Saga [`fork`](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/ForkModel.html) and [`cancel`](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/TaskCancellation.html)

Step by step, a solution to your specific implementation could be the following:

- import some more effects from `redux-saga`: `import { cancel, fork} from "redux-saga/effects";`
- let the `isEmail` saga dispatch an action at its very beginning to let the other sagas intercepts it and a reducer to set an `emailCheckRunning` flag. This action could be `yield put(EMAIL_CHECK_START)`
- let the `SAVE_EMAIL` update the `emailCheckRunning` flag to `false` with a reducer
- instead of `// ! OK, I CAN UPDATE NAME BECAUSE NEW NAME IS OK`, dispatch an action like `yield put(SAVE_NAME)`
- instead of `// ! OK, I CAN UPDATE EMAIL BECAUSE IT DOESN'T HAVE IN MY DB MYSQL`, dispatch an action like `yield put(SAVE_EMAIL)`
- in `settingsPageSaga` spawn/fork a new saga (the difference between them isn't relevant for your sample code, [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43259301/whats-the-difference-between-fork-and-spawn-in-redux-saga) if you want to know more about it)

```
yield fork(saveDataSaga);
```

- your `saveDataSaga` saga will look like this one

```
function* saveDataSaga() {
  let task;
  while(true) {
    // both ENTER_NEW_NAME and ENTER_NEW_EMAIL will start a new `saveDataNetworkFlow` saga
    yield take([ENTER_NEW_NAME, ENTER_NEW_EMAIL]);

    // but, before starting a new one, it cancels the previously forked `saveDataNetworkFlow` (if any)
    if(task) {
      yield cancel(task);
    }

    task = yield fork(saveDataNetworkFlow);
  }
}
```

- and the `saveDataNetworkFlow` saga is the following

```
function* saveDataNetworkFlow() {
  const action = yield take([SAVE_NAME, SAVE_EMAIL]);
  if(action.type === SAVE_NAME) {
    // wait some milliseconds to let the `isEmail` saga run
    yield wait(100);
  }

  // I assume that the `emailCheckRunning` flag is stored on top of your state, update it based on the shape of your own state
  const emailCheckRunning = yield select((globalState) => globalState.emailCheckRunning);

  if(emailCheckRunning) {
    yield take(SAVE_EMAIL);
  }

  yield call(saveData);
}
```

Let's analyze the different cases:

- simple `CHANGE_NAME` action

  - the `saveDataSaga` saga cancels any previous `saveDataNetworkFlow` saga
  - the `SAVE_NAME` action unlocks the `saveDataNetworkFlow` saga
  - the `saveDataNetworkFlow` saga wait for 100 milliseconds
  - there isn't any pending email check so the `saveDataNetworkFlow` call the `saveData` saga
- simple `CHANGE_EMAIL` action with valid AJAX check

  - the `saveDataSaga` saga cancels any previous `saveDataNetworkFlow` saga
  - the `SAVE_EMAIL` will unlock the `saveDataNetworkFlow` saga
  - there isn't a pending email check (remember the `SAVE_EMAIL` action gets a reducer set `emailCheckRunning` to false)
  - the `saveDataNetworkFlow` call the `saveData` saga
- simple `CHANGE_EMAIL` action with invalid AJAX check

  - the `saveDataSaga` saga cancels any previous `saveDataNetworkFlow` saga
  - the `SAVE_EMAIL` will unlock the `saveDataNetworkFlow` saga
  - there is a pending email check so the `saveDataNetworkFlow` waits for the `SAVE_EMAIL` action
  - the `SAVE_EMAIL` won't be dispatched, the `saveDataNetworkFlow` saga never ends and will be eventually canceled in the future
- `CHANGE_NAME` and `CHANGE_EMAIL` with valid AJAX check

  - the `saveDataSaga` saga cancels any previous `saveDataNetworkFlow` saga
  - the `SAVE_NAME` action unlocks the `saveDataNetworkFlow` saga
  - the `saveDataNetworkFlow` saga wait for 100 milliseconds
  - there is a pending email check so the `saveDataNetworkFlow` waits for the `SAVE_EMAIL` action
  - the `isEmail` saga dispatches a `SAVE_EMAIL`
  - the `saveDataNetworkFlow` call the `saveData` saga
- `CHANGE_NAME` and `CHANGE_EMAIL` with invalid AJAX check

  - the `saveDataSaga` saga cancels any previous `saveDataNetworkFlow` saga
  - the `SAVE_NAME` action unlocks the `saveDataNetworkFlow` saga
  - the `saveDataNetworkFlow` saga wait for 100 milliseconds
  - there is a pending email check, so the `saveDataNetworkFlow` waits for the `SAVE_EMAIL` action
  - the `SAVE_EMAIL` won't be dispatched, the `saveDataNetworkFlow` saga never ends and will be eventually canceled in the future
- `CHANGE_NAME` or `CHANGE_EMAIL` action dispatched while a previously saga is running

  - you need to implement the same cancellation logic for the `isName` and `isEmail` sagas to avoid any concurrency problem, here you can find [how to do it](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Concurrency.html) (it's the same guide that's at the base of this solution of mine)

I hope it could be helpful, let me know if you need something more

Note that:

- if the user submits the form twice while the first `saveData` is still waiting for the server response... two AJAX requests are going to hit the server. It's up to you to manage the Redux state with some reducers and avoiding the user to submit the form while the first request isn't finished yet.
  It doesn't make sense to cancel the AJAX request because once it has left the client, it could already take effect on the server.
- every canceled saga can manage its cancellation policy, the code to manage it is the following

```
import { cancelled } from 'redux-saga/effects'
function* saga() {
  try {
    // ... your code
  } finally {
    if (yield cancelled())
      // the saga has been cancelled
  }
}
```